# border not showing good at this color code `#dfe4e3`

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some border issue. `border-bottom` is working fine but `border-right` not working good, I don't know why this code behaving like this way , if i change the color code , its working fine take look here please

[image]

```css
.activities h2 {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #0e5e98;
  font-family: 'Reef-Bold';
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.activities p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'open_sansregular';
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  line-height: 21px;
}
.activities a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #0e5e98;
  font-family: 'Reef-Bold';
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.activities a:hover {
  color: #e72129;
}
.activities .col-lg-6 {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-right: 1px solid #dfe4e3;
}
.activities .col-lg-6:first-child,
.activities .col-lg-6:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfe4e3;
}
.activities .col-lg-6:nth-child(even) {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container activities">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 w100 text-center">
      <img src="images/kiddies_pool.png" alt="kiddies_pool" />
      <h2>Kiddies Pool</h2>
      <p>Future Kid Entertainment & Real Estate Company is a Kuwaiti shareholding company (K.S.C.C.) with a capital of over..</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 w100 text-center">
      <img src="images/speed_pool.png" alt="speed slide" />
      <h2>Speed Slide</h2>
      <p>Future Kid Entertainment & Real Estate Company is a Kuwaiti shareholding company (K.S.C.C.) with a capital of over..</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 w100 text-center">
      <img src="images/shot_gun_slide.png" alt="shot gun" />
      <h2>Shot Gun Slide</h2>
      <p>Future Kid Entertainment & Real Estate Company is a Kuwaiti shareholding company (K.S.C.C.) with a capital of over..</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 w100 text-center">
      <img src="images/cannon_ball_ride.png" alt="cannon" />
      <h2>Cannon Ball Ride</h2>
      <p>Future Kid Entertainment & Real Estate Company is a Kuwaiti shareholding company (K.S.C.C.) with a capital of over..</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

  </div>
</div>
```

then i have changed the color code `#dfe4e3` to `#000` now its working

```css
.activities h2 {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #0e5e98;
  font-family: 'Reef-Bold';
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.activities p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'open_sansregular';
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  line-height: 21px;
}
.activities a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #0e5e98;
  font-family: 'Reef-Bold';
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.activities a:hover {
  color: #e72129;
}
.activities .col-lg-6 {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.activities .col-lg-6:first-child,
.activities .col-lg-6:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfe4e3;
}
.activities .col-lg-6:nth-child(even) {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container activities">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 w100 text-center">
      <img src="images/kiddies_pool.png" alt="kiddies_pool" />
      <h2>Kiddies Pool</h2>
      <p>Future Kid Entertainment & Real Estate Company is a Kuwaiti shareholding company (K.S.C.C.) with a capital of over..</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 w100 text-center">
      <img src="images/speed_pool.png" alt="speed slide" />
      <h2>Speed Slide</h2>
      <p>Future Kid Entertainment & Real Estate Company is a Kuwaiti shareholding company (K.S.C.C.) with a capital of over..</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 w100 text-center">
      <img src="images/shot_gun_slide.png" alt="shot gun" />
      <h2>Shot Gun Slide</h2>
      <p>Future Kid Entertainment & Real Estate Company is a Kuwaiti shareholding company (K.S.C.C.) with a capital of over..</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 w100 text-center">
      <img src="images/cannon_ball_ride.png" alt="cannon" />
      <h2>Cannon Ball Ride</h2>
      <p>Future Kid Entertainment & Real Estate Company is a Kuwaiti shareholding company (K.S.C.C.) with a capital of over..</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

  </div>
</div>
```

May be this is a simple question but Please help me anybody to find the solution

Comment: I can't figure out, what isn't working, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: i think its working fine!

Comment: @AbhishekPandey did you check with first snippet , border right not good compared with border-bottom

Comment: the `border-right` property working well in your first html code it shows border in light bluish color.

Comment: please compare with border-bottom and border-right . both are same code

Comment: Is it browser specific problem? which browser are you using?

Comment: It's working fine here I think it's not working in your browser.

Comment: @UmangPatwa is your browser shows like this http://prntscr.com/dz49i2

Comment: @ `Down voters` i checked with all browsers , border-right is blurred in all browsers , please check with the print Screen i posted

Comment: @Naila yes it showing like attached screenshot.

Comment: Can you add screen shot of what you are getting? seems fine at my end.

Comment: @UmangPatwa yep that i am asking why its behaving like this,

Comment: the first snippet u shared is working fine for me man... i don't see how it is blurred

Comment: @Naila I am not sure what exactly you want. do you think `color` of `border-bottom` and `border-right` look different  when apply `#dfe4e3` value

Comment: yeah, you are right, do you know why ?

Answer (score -1):

I have just changed border size to check Is there any color difference but after changed border size I don't think that `border-bottom` and `border-right` `color` is different check this-

```css
I have some border issue. border-bottom is working fine but border-right not working good, I don't know why this code behaving like this way , if i change the color code , its working fine take look here please

enter image description here

Hide code snippet

.activities h2 {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #0e5e98;
  font-family: 'Reef-Bold';
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.activities p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'open_sansregular';
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  line-height: 21px;
}
.activities a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #0e5e98;
  font-family: 'Reef-Bold';
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.activities a:hover {
  color: #e72129;
}
.activities .col-lg-6 {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-right: 8px solid #dfe4e3;
}
.activities .col-lg-6:first-child,
.activities .col-lg-6:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom: 8px solid #dfe4e3;
}
.activities .col-lg-6:nth-child(even) {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container activities">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 w100 text-center">
      <img src="images/kiddies_pool.png" alt="kiddies_pool" />
      <h2>Kiddies Pool</h2>
      <p>Future Kid Entertainment & Real Estate Company is a Kuwaiti shareholding company (K.S.C.C.) with a capital of over..</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 w100 text-center">
      <img src="images/speed_pool.png" alt="speed slide" />
      <h2>Speed Slide</h2>
      <p>Future Kid Entertainment & Real Estate Company is a Kuwaiti shareholding company (K.S.C.C.) with a capital of over..</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 w100 text-center">
      <img src="images/shot_gun_slide.png" alt="shot gun" />
      <h2>Shot Gun Slide</h2>
      <p>Future Kid Entertainment & Real Estate Company is a Kuwaiti shareholding company (K.S.C.C.) with a capital of over..</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 w100 text-center">
      <img src="images/cannon_ball_ride.png" alt="cannon" />
      <h2>Cannon Ball Ride</h2>
      <p>Future Kid Entertainment & Real Estate Company is a Kuwaiti shareholding company (K.S.C.C.) with a capital of over..</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree with your suggestion there in no difference between  `border-right`  and  `border-bottom`

Comment: This is not what i need, i just want to know whats happening with border-width:1px

Comment: Form my point of view also there is no difference when `border-width:1px;`